# Jquery .css not working the first time it is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fullscreen class which (obviously) makes any panel it is added to full screen. The scss is the following :

```
.fullscreen-div {
  top: $navbar_height;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: white;
}
```

Whenever an other specific panel is open however i want the full screen to be a bit smaller so the other panel can fit too. I try to do this with the following javascript :

```
function setWindowDimensions(){
    ...
    //Fullscreen width
    var fullscreen = $('.fullscreen-div');
    if(leftPanelPresence){
        fullscreen.css("left", leftPanelWidth);
    }else{
        fullscreen.css("left", 0);
    }
}
```

This code is correctly run when the left panel is visible however the "left" style attribute fullscreen div only changes when i run this code twice. The first time it just stays the default left: 0; .

I checked if the jQuery element was correctly selected, id the leftPanelPresence was true and if the leftPanelWidth was set correctly which all seems to be the case.

The fullscreen button does the following (coffeescript):

```
$(document).on 'click', '.evidence-header h4 i.icon-resize-full', ->
    evidenceView.addClass('fullscreen-div')
    setWindowDimensions()
```

leftPanelWidth is set to 200 by default.

The .css jQuery line is run but i just don't see the change reflected in my browser. When i inspect the css in the browser it stays 0.

Comment: What is the value of `leftPanelWidth`?

Comment: Please show us more of your code, like how are you getting the values for the variables and how you're opening the panel

Comment: Do you really have `$navbar_height` in your css file??  (And no `.` before the class name)

Comment: There is a . in front of the fullscreen-div, i missed it while copying. Saas allows variables such as $navbar_height to be defined so yes, the $navbar_height is exactly like in my scss file.

Comment: If it's work in second time, "leftPanelPresence" variable has a problem. And with these code, I can't say more.

Answer (score -1):

the argument of .css must be a string as you would write it in .css file

you need to add 'px' at the end leftPanelWidth.

It works with your default value because 0 is interpreted as a null value and works without the 'px'

Comment: No, you don't.  jQuery is very friendly and does things like that for you :)  (It always assumes px, rather than another unit.)

Comment: I've tried it as a string with px and without. This makes no difference